# Switching Between Heroku's Remote Repos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, heroku

I'm facing a curious problem.

I'm running a Linux box, with two Desktops. Here's my environment:

Desktop 1: Running a pet project
Terminal 1
Heroku Login: my personal e-mail
Heroku App 1

Desktop 2: Running a real project
Terminal 2
Heroku Login:same as above: my personal e-mail
Heroku App 2

When I switch from Desktop 1 to Desktop 2, from my pet project to the real project, surprise! Terminal 2 is connected in **Heroku App 1**!

How can I fix this, keeping separate environments, properly switching between two Heroku's environments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Heroku Accounts cli plugin](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts).

```
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git

$ heroku accounts:add personal
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: david@heroku.com
Password: ******

Add the following to your ~/.ssh/config

Host heroku.personal
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile /PATH/TO/PRIVATE/KEY
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```